# Two integers x & y

Tags: java, integer

Given two int values, print whichever value is larger. However if the two values have the same remainder when divided by 5, then the print the smaller value. However, in all cases, if the two values are the same, print 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();

    if(x > y || (x%5 == y%5 && y > x))
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    else if (y > x || (x%5 == y%5 && x > y ))
    {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
    else if(x == y)
    {
        System.out.println("0");
    }
}
```

My score was 79/100 when I sent it to an online judge

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Off the top of my head: you didn't abstract this out to a method, and you assumed you would be getting the variables from `Scanner` input. That might warrant lower points.

Comment: You should ask yourself how you would write a unit test with this code? You can't do you? You mix IO operation with algorithm, it's really bad, it doesn't deserve 79 :p You should always send unit test with that kind of assignment, even when it is not explicitly asked, it's always bonus points.

Comment: Apart from questions of readability, the code doesn't implement the specification.  E.g. if x=10 and y=5 it will print x (by the first rule) whereas it should print y (by the second rule).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- What condition is the most important?

  It seems like `if (a == b)` is the most important, which is what you then should handle first and use `else` for the rest.
- Duplicated logic

  You have written `(x%5 == y%5 && y > x)` twice in your code.
- Using `Math.min` or `Math.max`

  Instead of using `if (x > y)` and `if (x < y)` you can let Java find out what is smaller or larger.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      int x = scan.nextInt();
      int y = scan.nextInt();

      if (x == y) {
          System.out.println(0);
      } else if (x % 5 == y % 5) {
          System.out.println(Math.min(x, y));
      } else {
          System.out.println(Math.max(x, y));
      }
  }
  ```

Note: I can't guarantee that this will give you 100 points. I can't even guarantee that this will give you more points than Caridorc's solution with ternaries. But in my opinion, this is the better solution.

Comment: Use _return early and often_ instead of `else`. Put the code into its own method where the `println()`s are replaced with `return` statements. This makes the code easier to follow and reduces/eliminates subsequent indentation. Code becomes: `public static int function(final int x, final int y) {
    if (x == y)
       return 0;
       
    if (x % 5 == y % 5)
      return Math.min(x, y);
    
    return Math.max(x, y);
}` and then in `main()`: `System.out.println(function(x,y));`

Answer (score 7):

One of the problem, I think, is that you should check if both number are equals before doing anything else. Why bother doing arithmetic computing (in your ifs) for nothing?

Also, you should have a method that solves your problem, and do the IO in the `main` method, not all-in-one.

But the main problem is that you repeat your conditions. Here `x > y` is written twice :

```
if(x > y || (x%5 == y%5 && y > x))
```

And you repeat `x%5 == y%5` twice.

You should first check if their modulos are equal, then check for which is bigger. Which gives something like this :

```
//Naming is hard in such a case.
private static int computeStuff(int x, int y) {
    if(x == y) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x % 5 == y % 5) {
        return Math.min(x,y);
    }
    return Math.max(x,y);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(computeStuff(x,y));
}
```

(Note also the spacing is slightly clearer now)

This way, your `computeStuff` method has its own responsability and using `return` makes it clearer (in my opinion). The `main` method takes care of IO!

Comment: As @Simon said, I don't know if this would give you 100%, but it should yield a better score :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably it's because of duplicated expressions:

```
x%5 == y%5
```

These modulos are more expensive and are evaluated twice if x and y are equal, which means that modulo operation is unneccesary.

Answer (score 2):

This is surely going to be controversial, but I suggest a nested ternary.

- This uses less code, such a trivial problem does not need so much code in my opinion.
- Ternaries are expressions, that are much easier to reason about than statements.
- This is easier to change, as just what is needed is written, avoiding for example the repetition of `System.out.println`
- This is faster, as the compiler is very good at optimizing ternaries.
- This uses the built-ins `Math.min` and `Math.max` to simplify the code and make it nicely fit inside a ternary.

```
System.out.println( x == y ? 0 :
                      x % 5 == y % 5 ? Math.min(x, y) :
                        Math.max(x, y) );
```

Comment: You were right, it is controversial! :)

Comment: @SimonForsberg the thing I really do not like is having to repeat `System.out.println` three times, something will be printed all times, so it should be taken out from the conditional branch .... for example in ruby `if x else y` is an expression, so you can avoid the ternary and write just one print, but here in Java...

Comment: @Caridorc In that case a method might be more suitable. ;)

Comment: @Caridorc TopinFrassi solves that in a nice way, and in my code it could be solved by introducing a local variable. You don't have to write `System.out.println` three times, but just because you don't do that doesn't mean you have to use a nested ternary.

Comment: @SimonForsberg his solution is also good in my opinion, I upvoted it.

Comment: I think @Caridorc just loves the one-liners too much :p

Comment: @SimonForsberg, I'm not really sure what your problem with the ternary is.  It is concise and quite readable in this case, far more so than the thicket of brackets and wasted lines that is the `if else` solution.  What everyone else does, or what the standard Java style guide says to do, is not always best.

Comment: ChatRoom if anyone is pro or opposite to ternaries -> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30509/ternary-vs-if  subjective discussions are better in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Two numbers have the same remainder when divided by 5 iff their difference is divisible by 5. So you can save yourself one `%` operation (which is expensive!) by simply doing:

```
public static int result(int x, int y) {
    if (x == y) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((x-y) % 5 == 0) {
        return Math.min(x, y);
    }
    else {
        return Math.max(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remainder and modulus is not the same thing. `-1 % 5 = -1`, `-1 mod 5 = 4`.

Comment: @Johnbot I don't understand what your point is. There is no `mod` function.

Comment: `3 % 5 = 3`, `Integer.MIN_VALUE % 5 = -3` but `(3 - Integer.MIN_VALUE) % 5 = 0`.

Comment: @Johnbot Perhaps the reason OP got 79/100 is because the grader isn't using Java's definition of modulo?

Comment: Well this answer gets the min of  `x` and `y` when they are congruent modulo 5 so this in not the same as the OP code. Yours is equivalent to using `Math.floorMod( x, 5 ) == Math.floorMod(y, 5)` and `(x - y)` may overflow.

Comment: The `else`s are useless here because of the `return` statements.